# Integrating three.js and plotly.js

Tags: javascript, html, graph, three.js, plotly.js

I am trying to plot a 3d network using three.js. The nodes of
the three.js graph network is associated with array of values. I want these
values to be plotted using plotly.js when nodes are clicked.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Three.js & Plotly integration</title>
  <style>
    #three-js-container {
      width: 70%;
      height: 400px;
      float: left;
    }

    #plotly-container {
      width: 30%;
      height: 400px;
      float: right;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="three-js-container"></div>
  <div id="plotly-container"></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.0/build/three.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/plotly.js@1.55.3/dist/plotly.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Three.js code for network graph
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth * 0.7, 400);
    document.querySelector("#three-js-container").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Values of nodes
    var values = [
      [10, 15, 20, 25],
      [5, 10, 15, 20]
    ];

    // Create node1
    var node1 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 32, 32);
    var node1Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
    var node1Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(node1, node1Material);
    node1Mesh.position.set(-10, 0, 0);
    scene.add(node1Mesh);

    // Create node2
    var node2 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 32, 32);
    var node2Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
    var node2Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(node2, node2Material);
    node2Mesh.position.set(10, 0, 0);
    scene.add(node2Mesh);

    // Create edge
    var edge = new THREE.Line(
      new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( [
        new THREE.Vector3( node1Mesh.position.x, node1Mesh.position.y, node1Mesh.position.z ),
        new THREE.Vector3( node2Mesh.position.x, node2Mesh.position.y, node2Mesh.position.z )
      ] ),
      new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, linewidth: 2 } )
    );
    scene.add(edge);

    camera.position.z = 20;

    var animate = function () {
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
    };
    animate();

    // Event listener to detect click on edge
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    document.querySelector("#three-js-container").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
      mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
      raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
      var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([edge]);
      if (intersects.length > 0) {
        // Show plotly graph on side panel
        Plotly.newPlot('side-panel', [{
          x: [0, 1, 2, 3],
          y: values[0],
          type: 'scatter'
        }, {
          x: [0, 1, 2, 3],
          y: values[1],
          type: 'scatter'
        }], {
          title: 'Values of Nodes'
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the plotly line graph is not visible when the three.js nodes are clicked.
Suggestions on how to fix this will be really helpful.

Comment: There is no type `line` in plotly, you have to use `scatter` instead. Also, where are your x values?

Comment: @mit Thanks, I corrected these (please see the update) and it's still not working. I see this error `DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` in the console. Could you please suggest how to fix this?